# Intersection of a manifold with open set

Tags: multivariable-calculus, manifolds

I'm using Flemming's book Function of Several Variables.

In it, the author defines Manifolds like this:
Let $1\le r\lt n,\ q\ge1$. A nonempty set $M \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ is a manifold of dimension $r$ and class $C^{(q)}$ if $M$ has the property that for every point $\mathbf{x_0} \in M$, there exists a neighbourhood $U$ of $\mathbf{x_0}$ and a $\mathbf{\Phi}=(\Phi^1,\dots,\Phi^{n-r})$ of class $C^{(q)}$ on $U$, such that $D\mathbf{\Phi}(\mathbf{x})$ has rank $n-r$ for every $\mathbf{x} \in U$ and

$M \cap U= \{\mathbf{x}\in U :\mathbf{\Phi}(\mathbf{x})=0 \}$.

Sidenote: Usually we take $U=\{\mathbf{x}:rank(D\mathbf{\Phi}(\mathbf{x}))=n-r \}$ and $M=\{\mathbf{x}:\mathbf{\Phi}(\mathbf{x})=0 \}$. This gives the manifold determined by $\mathbf{\Phi}$.

Having this definition in mind, we are asked to prove that $M\cap A$ is a $r$-manifold, when $A$ is an open set.

1)
This exercise seems so simple, that I'm afraid I'm not understanding it. =D $\\$ Isn't it enough to assume the same $\mathbf{\Phi}$ and $U$ of M and it will satisfy the definition for $M\cap A$? We also need to prove that $\mathbf{\Phi}$ restricted to $U\cap A$ is still of class $C^1$. But when is the restriction of a continuous function, also continuous? Is it in this case?

2) Wouldn't this also work if $A$ was closed? Why?

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks ;)

Answer (score 1):

I know I'm late on this, but I just saw the question, knew the answer and figured I'd post it.

1) a) The exercise is simple, but it's not enough to assume the same $\Phi$ and $U$ as in the definition. Almost, but not quite, as there's an extra step involved :)

Instead, let $M$ and $A$ be as defined in the question, and pick any $x \in M \cap A$. WLOG, $M \cap A \ne\emptyset$, otherwise the statement is false.

Since $M$ is a manifold, there exists a neighborhood $U$ of $x_0$ and a $\Phi=(\Phi^1,\dots,\Phi^{n-r})$ of class $C^{(q)}$ on $U$, such that $D\Phi(x)$ has rank $n-r$ for every ${x} \in U$ and $M \cap U= \{x\in U :\Phi(x)=0 \}$. Further, since $A$ is open, there exists an open neighborhood $U'$ of $x_0$ such that $U' \subset A$.

So let $V := U \cap U'$. Then $V \subset (M \cap A)$, $V \subset U$ and $V$ is a neighborhood of $x_0$.

Also, let $f := \Phi_{|V}$. Then $f= (f^1,...f^{n-r})=(\Phi^1,\dots,\Phi^{n-r})$ is of class $C^{(q)}$ on $V$, such that $Df(x)$ has rank $n-r$ for every ${x} \in V$ and $M \cap V= M \cap A \cap V =\{x\in V :\Phi(x)=f(x)=0 \}$.

Since $x_0$ was arbitrary, it follows from the definition that $M \cap A$ is a manifold of dimension $r$.

b) As for the second question, yes, a restriction of a continuous function $g: X \to Y$ to an arbitrary set $B \subset X$, $g_{|B}$, *is* continuous. Namely, take any open set V in $Y$ and let $U = g^{-1}(V)$ and $U' = g_{|B}^{-1}(V).$ Then $U$ us is open in $X$ and $U' = U \cap B$, so that $U'$ is open relative to $B$. Hence, $g_{|B}$, is continuous.

2) No, it wouldn't work. Take any straight line in $\mathbb{R}^2$ and let the point $x$ lie on it. Then $\{x\}$ is closed in $\mathbb{R}^2$. But the straight line is a manifold of dimension 1, whereas the intersection is a manifold of dimension 0.